# Googlemock incorrectly reporting error at test exit. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, testing, googlemock

Googlemock is incorrectly reporting problem at test exit.  What am I doing wrong?  I have scoured the googlemock documentation, but there is no good complete example, and nothing describing the problem I am having.

The error I get is:

```
googlemocktest.cpp(53): ERROR: this mock object should be deleted but never is.
Its address is @0018FDC4.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
```

The code for a simple test is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual ~IBar() {}
    virtual void b() = 0;
    virtual int c(std::string) = 0;
};

class Foo
{
private:
    IBar *bar_;
public:
    Foo(IBar *bar);
    int a();
};

Foo::Foo(IBar *bar)
    : bar_(bar)
{
}

int Foo::a()
{
//  bar_->b();
    return bar_->c("hello");
}

class BarMock : public IBar
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(b, void());
    MOCK_METHOD1(c, int(std::string));
};

using ::testing::Return;

void TestAFunctionInFoo()
{
    try
    {
        BarMock barMock;
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> newFoo(new Foo(&barMock));

        EXPECT_CALL(barMock, b());
        EXPECT_CALL(barMock, c("hello")).WillOnce(Return(42));

        newFoo->a();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Mock exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true;
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, &argv[0]);
    TestAFunctionInFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

I have verified with a debugger that IBar::~IBar() is indeed getting called.  But I still get this error message.  If I uncomment the call to IBar::b() in Foo::a(), then there is no test failure so the catch statement doesn't get called.  IBar::~IBar() is called, but there is no error message indicating a mock object isn't deleted.

Thank you very, very much for your help!

Comment: Bleh, no answer I'm afraid, but confirmed your behaviour with gtest/gmock 1.5 on Fedora 15 with gcc 4.6.1. Have you tried the gmock list/group?

Comment: Just wanted to point out for posterity that, although it's not the problem in your case, the same error appears when you forget the virtual destructor on your mocked interface – this is quite subtle and can make you stare at the code for quite a while…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because you have enabled `throw_on_failure` flag - as it's mentioned in [Google Mock ForDummies](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies):

> This approach has a catch: it makes Google Mock throw an exception from a mock object's destructor sometimes.

Since an exception is thrown from destructor, mock object is never fully deleted and framework complains about it when program ends.

The simplest solution to this problem is to use Google Test as unit testing framework and have `throw_on_failure` flag disabled (default state) - GTest automatically fails test if mock expectations are not met within.

If you cannot use Google Test because you're using another framework (e.g. CppUnit) you can rewrite your test body this way:

```
void TestAFunctionInFoo()
{
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true;
    BarMock barMock;

    try
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> newFoo(new Foo(&barMock));

        EXPECT_CALL(barMock, b());
        EXPECT_CALL(barMock, c("hello")).WillOnce(Return(42));

        newFoo->a();
        ::testing::Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(&barMock);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        // expectations failed - do whatever you want 
    }

    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = false;
}
```

`VerifyAndClearExpectations(void*)` checks if given mock expectations are met - if not and `throw_on_failure` flag is enabled it throws an exception.

This way your mock object will be destroyed properly, and you will still have an exception if something has gone wrong.

BTW: Avoid using `catch (...) { }` - it's generally bad idea, which in most cases proves poor code quality.

Comment: Can you give a link to the documentation? The place where that link redirects to doesn't seem to have the documentation for throw_on_failure

Comment: It's been a few years now, but here's what the documentation said at the time of placing this answer: https://web.archive.org/web/20120104220454/http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies#Using_Google_Mock_with_Any_Testing_Framework